# Trying to make a new column with existing column that have 'int' and 'string'

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

```
data = pd.read_csv(r'RE_absentee_one.csv')
data['New_addy'] = str(data['Prop-House Number']) + data['Prop-Street Name'] + data['Prop-Mode'] + str(data['Prop-Apt Unit Number'])
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Name','New_addy'])
```

So this is the code

As you can see Prop-House Number and Prop-Apt Number are both int, and the rest are strings, I am trying to combine all these so that the full address is under one column labeled 'New addy'

Comment: What's the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow the string assignment with each variable using map as mentioned below:

```
data = pd.read_csv(r'RE_absentee_one.csv')
data['New_addy'] = data['Prop-House Number'].map(str) + data['Prop-Street Name'].map(str) + data['Prop-Mode'].map(str) + data['Prop-Apt Unit Number'].map(str)
#select the desired columns for further work
data = data[['Name','New_addy']]
```

Comment: Please mark this answer if it resolves your query.

Comment: Is it possible to add spaces for the columns I just created?

Comment: To add space, use " " like this one...data['Prop-House Number'].map(str) + " " + data['Prop-Street Name'].map(str)

Answer (score 0):

One way is using list comprehension:

```
data['New_addy'] = [str(n) + street + mode + str(apt_n) for n,street,mode,apt_n in zip(
    data['Prop-House Number'],data['Prop-Street Name'],data['Prop-Mode'],data['Prop-Apt Unit Number'])]
```

Comment: So I used what you gave me and got this -TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "float") to str